# How to split message into more messages

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

if I have a kstream with KVs like `<String, List<myobject>>` that I obtained from a KStream groupby + aggregate, is there a way to split each of the values of the List<> to get individual messages like `<String, myobject>`?  I was hoping for something like flattening a list that would return individual messages with the same key, but I couldn't find which method from the kstream (if any) might help.
I grouped them to do some transformations more easily, but then, when I want to send those messages to an output topic I'd prefer to send them individually.
Thanks!

Comment: I have not used it, but I think [`KStream#flatMapValues`](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#flatMapValues-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper-) would do it: `kstream.flatMapValues(list -> list)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.flatMapValues() - Create a new KStream by transforming the value of each record in this stream into zero or more values with the same key in the new stream.

Passing your list to this method, followed up with `.to(destinationTopic)` should do the trick.

Comment: Just to be sure, flatMapValues seems to return an Iterable of values. I want to extract each value of a List into individual kafka messages. Is this correct? It seems weird to me that if I want to get rid of a List<>, I get one in the output. Could you share a sample? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you need to return an iterable to `.flatMapValues()` so that the processor node can iterate through the elements - sending a record for each element in the list. 
For instance, the notorious wordCount Kafka streams example. If you have a sentence, and want to break that sentence down into words to be send as individual records, you would:
 `stream<String, String>.flatMapValues(sentence -> Arrays.toList(sentence.split(on_space)));` So you return a List, which is an iterable, and behind the scenes the operator will publish each element in the list as its own record.